# Laravel: Add new column on DDBB without remove the data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And now I want to add a new column, and looks like this:

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('slug');
                $table->string('pathlogo')->default('/');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

How can I make just an 'add column' on Laravel? I don't want to do php artisan migrate:refresh, or restart and then make again seed.

Now I have some data in DB which not exist on seed I just want to make a new column.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns

Comment: @user2486 Doctrine isn't necessary. Laravel has the options right out of the box.

Comment: @user2486 The OP wants to add a column, not modify it.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `Schema::create` to `Schema::table` (because you are not creating a table, just selecting it), and then your only line in that function should be:

```
$table->string('pathlogo')->default('/')->after('slug');
```

`after` will ensure the column is positioned how you want.

If you are still in development, ie. you don't have data in the table, you should just rollback all your migrations and edit the original.

Comment: And if I have data and only want to add the new field? @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Create a new migration and Use that as your up function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('pathlogo')->default('/');
    });
}
```

them migrate as normal.